# Printing out contents of as Jenkins folder during test execution

Tags: selenium, jenkins

Is it possible to print out contents from a jenkins folder e.g.

```
/var/jenkins_home/jobs/[jobName]/workspace/targets
```

while a test is running, with the outcome being a list of all folders and files etc.

Comment: You certainly can, you can run shell commands to list directories and files as long as run it on the right node(master vs slave)

Answer (score 0):

You're able to do it.
If you use pipeline it will be something like this:

```
sh "ls -lhtr targets"
```

If you use freestyle job it will be "Execute shell" command where you can user same command:

```
ls -lhtr targets
```